# How to add jQuery event to all current and future elements?

Tags: jquery, binding, jquery-selectors, delegates

I just noticed that `live()` is already deprecated in jQuery. I have quick question (just to make sure which method is the most efficient, the fastest and up-to-date). I've got `myfunction()` and I want to `bind()` it to all current and future elements with `attr("title") == 'x'`.

Is this what I should use:

```
jQuery("???").bind("mouseup", myfunction);
jQuery("???").bind("keyup", myfunction);
```

Or this:

```
jQuery("???").delegate("???", "mouseup", myfunction);
jQuery("???").delegate("???", "keyup", myfunction);
```

Or this:

```
jQuery("???").on("mouseup", "???", myfunction);
jQuery("???").on("keyup", "???", myfunction);
```

I'm also having problem specifying correct selector(s) - because some of them allow to attach event to one thing (like body or document) and they allow second selector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, with an [*attribute equals selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '[title="x"]', myfunction);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for :) I think that the question is already answered.

Comment: @Paul: Also, if you have a common parent to the elements that match the selector `[title="x"]`, replace `$(document)` with `$("#id_of_common_parent")` as it will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing - what if I want to use "contentEditable" instead of "Title" and "contentEditable" can be: (1) `contentEditable="contentEditable"`, (2) `contentEditable="true"` or just `contentEditable`. Those are 3 attributes that mark is as `true` - in case of `title="x"` there is just 1 possibility. That's the second case I need it for.

Comment: Thanks! Great! That answers all my questions :)

Comment: @Paul: Use the following instead: `$('[contentEditable]').filter(function() {
    var attrValue = $(this).attr("contentEditable");
    var allowedValues = ['', 'contentEditable', 'true'];
    return ~allowedValues.indexOf(attrValue);
});`. The other expression will not match just `contentEditable`. This one will http://jsfiddle.net/QLgTd/1/.

Comment: Thank you! It's great that you checked this. Official specification of `contenteditable` attribute mentions only (true|false|inherit) actually, so I think I made a little mistake here BUT your answer covers more (and more complex) cases thanks to this mistake. Thank you for looking into this - I already tested the code and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

The syntax that replaces `.live()` is like this:

```
$('#parent').on('keyup mouseup', '.children', myfunction);
```

Comment: Good to know that I can mix two events together using this. Thanks! I'm also wondering what would be my selector - and why did they write that `live()` is not efficient? Is it the same with `on()`?

Comment: There's a list of problems with `.live()` in the API page for that method: http://api.jquery.com/live/